# Why does this comment get passed as an argument in Javascript/React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working through [this React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and more specifically with the simple code below from this [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VbbVLg?editors=0010).

I added a comment (`HERE IS THE COMMENT`) to one of the lines concluding a tag, as you can see:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
      > // HERE IS THE COMMENT
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As it turns out, this *comment* actually modifies the arguments passed to the Square component. Without the comment, the code renders a 3x3 grid with nothing inside, but with the comment, whatever is in the comment gets rendered in the squares (in this case, "HERE IS THE COMMENT")

Why is that?

Comment: Why is because it is inside the tag and is therefore just text there. To have comment inside content of tag need `{/* my comment */}`

Answer (score 3):

That's not a jsx comment, but try turn `// HERE IS THE COMMENT` into a real react comment

`{/* COMMENT */}`

Answer (score 3):

It is because this syntax is neither a string nor HTML. It is JSX, as you know (or you don't), an extension to Javascript. So, when you try to comment as you do it's seen as a text here:

```
<button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
> 
        // HERE IS THE COMMENT
        {this.state.value}
</button>
```

This is no different than doing:

```
<button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
> 
        SOME TEXT HERE
        {this.state.value}
</button>
```

React renders as a text as you can see. But it works in HTML part:

```
<button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
        // HERE IS THE COMMENT
> 
        {this.state.value}
</button>
```

So, if you don't want to render your comment as a text to the DOM, you will use one of the goodies of JSX which is the Javascript expression here. When you want to use an expression like that, you should use curly braces. So:

```
<button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.setState({value: 'X'})}
>
        { */  HERE IS THE COMMENT */ }
        {this.state.value}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

by the way in VS code (thanks, guys!) you can comment out react with hotkey (cmd /), and IDE knows when to add // comment and when {/* comment */}

Basically, inside JSX you should always use  {/* comment */}, but sometimes when pair of curly braces is already used /* comment */ is ok too.

Answer (score 0):

React JSX uses a different comment syntax than JavaScript (and HTML).

The `Game` component uses proper JSX comments (`{/* status */}` and `{/* TODO */}`):

```js
class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

JSX is conceptually like HTML, so whatever you put between the tags will be rendered to the page.

In this case, you're adding text (`// HERE IS THE COMMENT`) within the `<button>` tags in the `render` function of the `Square` Component which is being "rendered" in every instance of `Square`.

A simplified version to show you what's happening (HTML):

`<p>// HERE IS THE COMMENT</p>`

---

I personally use the [language-babel](https://atom.io/packages/language-babel) package in Atom and use the `.jsx` extension in any files that contain JSX. Babel gives me syntax highlighting and adds comments properly when using the keyboard shortcut.